# Radio Change Audio Value onClick

Tags: javascript, function

I'm making a project using audio.

And I need to change the value of this

```js
const click1 = new Audio (changeAudio());
```

I have these radio inputs to choose from with the value I want to use:

```html
<div class="sound-selector">
                <input type="radio" name="sound" value="Pato" id="Duck" onClick="changeAudio()" checked> 
                <label>Pato</label>
                <input type="radio" name="sound" value="Perro" id="Dog" onClick="changeAudio()" >
                <label>Perro</label>
                <input type="radio" name="sound" value="Gato" id="Cat" onClick="changeAudio()">
                <label>Gato</label>
                <input type="radio" name="sound" value="Vaca" id="Cow" onClick="changeAudio()">
                <label>Vaca</label>
            </div>
```

I use this function:

```js
function changeAudio() {

    if (document.getElementById('Duck').checked) {return 'url'};
    if (document.getElementById('Dog').checked) {return 'url'};
    if (document.getElementById('Cat').checked) {return 'url'};
    if (document.getElementById('Cow').checked) {return 'url'};
}
```

Now. The sound selected needs to be played with a start button and if I have changed the selector just clicking sounds has to change without stopping playing. I couldn't make it.

I need some help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that. I changed a little your markup to make it more general use (and semantically accurate), and as for the script part - i added notes inside snippet.

```js
// start with iteration over your inputs:
document.querySelectorAll('[name="sound"]').forEach(element => {  
  // listen to change event:
  element.addEventListener('change',function() {  
    // decide what audio to play when checkbox is checked
    switch (element.id) {
      case 'demo1':
      var audio = new Audio('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3');
      break;
      case 'demo2':
      var audio = new Audio('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3');
      break;
      case 'demo3':
      var audio = new Audio('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3');
      break;
    }
    // play 
    audio.play();          
  });
});
```

```html
<fieldset class="sound-selector">
  <label>Demo1
    <input type="radio" name="sound" id="demo1" />
  </label>
  <label>Demo2
    <input type="radio" name="sound" id="demo2" />
  </label>
  <label>Demo3
    <input type="radio" name="sound" id="demo3" />
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

***mp3 files taken from: https://www.soundhelix.com/audio-examples***